# What order are grid search combinations handled in sklearn?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I have a question about the order in which sklearn's GridSearchCV object handles its hyperparameter combinations. Specifically, I performed a gridsearch using sklearn with parameters:

```
param1 = [val1, val2, val3, val4, val5]
param2 = [num1, num2]
```

The `mean_test_score` attribute of `cv_results_` is an array of length 10 as expected ( `len(param1)*len(param2)` ); however, I do not know which value corresponds to what combination. That is, are the values of `param1` held which `param2` is cycled or vice versa.

That is, do the 10 values in `mean_test_score` correspond to

```
[ [val1, num1], [val1, num2], [val2, num1], [val2, num2], ... ]
```

(where `param2` is cycled before `param1`) or

```
[ [val1, num1], [va2, num1], [val3, num1], [val4, num1], [val5, num1], [val1, num2], ... ]
```

(where `param1` is cycled before `param2`). Does it just depend on the order in which they are specified in the grid search? Can I return the results along one specific hyperparameter value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` uses the class named `ParameterGrid` inside, that you can check [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L47) (lines 47, 114)

This is more or less what `ParameterGrid` does inside your `GridSearchCV`:

```
from itertools import product

grid_values= [{"param1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "param2": [1, 2]}]

def grid(grid_values):
    for p in grid_values:
        # Always sort the keys of a dictionary, for reproducibility
        print(p)
        items = sorted(p.items())
        if not items:
            yield {}
        else:
            keys, values = zip(*items)
            for v in product(*values):
                params = dict(zip(keys, v))
                yield params
```

- It first of all wrap your dict in a list (because it can handle different kind of data as input, for example a list of dicts)

  ```
  grid_values= [{"param1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "param2": [1, 2]}]
  ```
- **after that it performs a sort on the keys of your dict, for reproducibility purpose. Which will determine your combinations**

  ```
    items = sorted(p.items())
  ```
- then it uses the `product` function from `itertools` that does what you thought ([here details](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)). A nested for loop on your variables. But starting with values sorted by the parameters' names!

  ```
  for v in product(*values):
      params = dict(zip(keys, v))
      yield params
  ```

[Check also the doc of ParameterGrid](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(clf.cv_results_)
```

The columns `param_param1` and `param_param2` will should you the corresponding params for each combination.

Of course, you can also iterate it using a common index but using pandas is very easy.

Comment: I think OP is interested in how the order of the parameters combinations is generated